# Handlebars gives an error when loading the application in an iFrame only in IE11 above

Tags: javascript, iframe, handlebars.js

I am getting following error from Handlebars when I am running the application within an iframe only in IE11 above. I have tested application directly without loading via iFrame in IE11 above and works perfectly well. Also works fine in IE10 as well.

Also in all other browsers(Chrome/Firefox/Safari) application works fine within an iFrame and standalone.

```
{{cms 'DS
------^
Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please comment the whole line with that error , i mean the line with {{cms

Comment: @ArunRMenon unfortunately that is all it gives as the error. However cms is just a custom helper. Having said that it's nothing to do with the custom helper and if go to a different page then HB throws error in another tag. Maybe you are wondering why I am saying that is nothing to do with custom tags. That is because app is simply working when it loads directly and issue only comes up when app get loads in an iFrame and only in IE11 +

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by adding following meta tag which forces app to run on IE10 mode. Still I am not sure what is the actual issue.`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">`